# Create a dotted path that follows a curve

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a design I'm trying to port over to code, the design is as follows:

[image]

I've created the majority of the design in code already (just a prototype so the html/css isn't perfect), but the area I'm struggling with is the dotted progression that you can see within the curved path

```css
.frame {
  width: 375px;
  height: 750px;
  background: #171B42;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #171B42, #171B42 50%, #3C98FF 110%);
  position: relative;
}

#earth {
   position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.locked {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 76px auto;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
}

.locked img {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 26px;
}

.locked.row-1:after {
    content: "";
    width: 163px;
    height: 175px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/u6v9Dkd.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: -130px;
    right: -50px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.locked.row-2:after {
content: "";
    width: 163px;
    height: 175px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/u6v9Dkd.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: -127px;
    left: -46px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.path-map {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 180px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
  width:375px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  
  <div class="path-map">
    
    <div class="locked row-2">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
    </div>
    
    <div class="locked row-1">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  
  <img id="earth" src="https://i.imgur.com/RR8kQx1_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand"/>
</div>
```

I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to create that dotted path, it might require some javascript? I'm not entirely sure what the best way of solving this would be outside of just manually adding each dot with `position: absolute`.

Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Comment: You should look into using an SVG path element with a dashed stroke applied to it

Comment: @Sean, I appreciate the comment, I'm unsure that would work as the dots have 2 colors to show progress... if you think it could work, do you mind elaborating a little? Thanks

Comment: You could use two path elements with different colored strokes—one on top of the other—and mask one to show progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how this can be done using SVG [`<path>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path) elements, [`<use>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) elements, a [`<mask>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) element, the [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap) attribute, and the [`stroke-linecap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap) attribute.

You can define a single `<path>` element once, and then reuse it multiple times with different stroke styles or masks applied to it, which is especially handy in this case.

```css
body { background: darkblue; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 515 515">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect fill="black" x="0" y="0" width="515" height="515"></rect>
      <rect fill="white" x="0" y="200" width="515" height="315"></rect>
    </mask>
    <path id="path" fill="none" d="M138 414C192.333 414 312.8 414 360 414C419 414 504 262 360 262C216 262 261 262 153 262C45 262 39 130 144 130C249 130 327 130 378 130C429 130 452 83 452 -2C452 -87 472 -87 452 -87"></path>
  </defs>
  <!-- solid wide line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="20"></use>
  <!-- solid narrow line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="10"></use>
  <!-- dotted full line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 10" stroke-linecap="round"></use>
  <!-- dotted masked line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 10" stroke-linecap="round" mask="url(#mask)"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this, seems like a great solution

Comment: I just realized that this will look weird when the `y` of the white `rect` is on the same level as the horizontal dotted part.. it fills all the dots with half white, any idea on how to specify each dot should be filled/empty?

Comment: instead of a rectangle you could use that same path again with a thick stroke to be the mask, using stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I tried applying it to this codepen, but I'm struggling slightly.. would you mind checking it out? https://codepen.io/SimonKomlos/pen/zYqRaqW I've never worked with svg's before so it's a little foggy for me..